# Counting repeated characters in a string in a row Python

Tags: python

I would like to check a string for repeated characters in a row until the next space.

For example:
The following string has 4 O's in a row and I would like to detect that somehow.
`myString = 'I contain foooour O's in a row without any space'`

It doesnt matter what character it is as long as It's being repeated 4 times in a row without any space.

How can I achieve this and what are my options?

Comment: Your question is unclear: what do you mean by "detect"? What would be your exact expected output? What if there are many repetitions of the same/different characters? Please clarify. But whatever the output you expect, note that this question has certainly already been asked and answered here...

Comment: Just a way to detect it. Doesn't matter if it's a function returning true or if there is a regex you can use for a situation like this. I just want options. The closest question I could find was a question regarding how many repeated character in a string, not in a row in said string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One general solution might be to use `re.findall` with the pattern `((\S)\2{3,})`:

```py
myString = "I contain foooour O's in a row without any space"
matches = re.findall(r'((\S)\2{3,})', myString)
print(matches[0][0])
```

This prints:

```
oooo
```

Comment: Can you explain please what each part means? especially \2 part

Comment: `\2` is the second capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myString = "I contain foooour O's in a row without any space"

def count_repeat(some_string):
    counter = 1
    max_counter = 0
    tmp = some_string[0]
    for i in range(1, len(some_string)):
        if tmp == some_string[i] and some_string[i] != " ":
            counter += 1
        else:
            max_counter = counter if max_counter < counter else max_counter
            counter = 1
        tmp = some_string[i]
    return max_counter

print(count_repeat(myString))
```

Output

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

myString = "I contain foooour O's in a row without any space"

alphabet_lowercase = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
alphabet_uppercase = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

for index in range(26):
    if alphabet_lowercase[index] * 4 in myString:
        print(f"Found {alphabet_lowercase[index]}")
    if alphabet_uppercase[index] * 4 in myString:
        print(f"Found {alphabet_uppercase[index]}")
```

The above code will display any character that is repeated 4 times in a row. It will print the character that is repeated.